# Getting Data into ExpandableListview

Tags: android, expandablelistview

Hello sorry if this is an easy question, but I have a Problem getting Data into an Expandable ListView, im just stuck. This is the custom Adapter I have:

```
package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ui.FSettings;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.R;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> expandableListTitle;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail;

    public CustomExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> expandableListTitle,
                                       HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail) {
        this.context = context;
        this.expandableListTitle = expandableListTitle;
        this.expandableListDetail = expandableListDetail;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .get(expandedListPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return expandedListPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int listPosition, final int expandedListPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String expandedListText = (String) getChild(listPosition, expandedListPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate( R.layout.list_item, null);
        }
        TextView expandedListTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.expandedListItem);
        expandedListTextView.setText(expandedListText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListDetail.get(this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int listPosition) {
        return this.expandableListTitle.get(listPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.expandableListTitle.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int listPosition) {
        return listPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int listPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String listTitle = (String) getGroup(listPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.
                    getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }
        TextView listTitleTextView = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.listTitle);
        listTitleTextView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        listTitleTextView.setText(listTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int listPosition, int expandedListPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is the structure, which pumps data into the View.

```
package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest.ui.FSettings;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ExpandableListDataPump {
    public static HashMap<String, List<String>> getData() {
        HashMap<String, List<String>> expandableListDetail = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        List<String> cricket = new ArrayList<String>();
        cricket.add("India");
        cricket.add("Pakistan");
        cricket.add("Australia");
        cricket.add("England");
        cricket.add("South Africa");

        List<String> football = new ArrayList<String>();
        football.add("Brazil");
        football.add("Spain");
        football.add("Germany");
        football.add("Netherlands");
        football.add("Italy");

        List<String> basketball = new ArrayList<String>();
        basketball.add("United States");
        basketball.add("Spain");
        basketball.add("Argentina");
        basketball.add("France");
        basketball.add("Russia");

        List<String> ass = new ArrayList<String>();
        ass.add("United States");
        ass.add("Spain");
        ass.add("Argentina");
        ass.add("France");
        ass.add("Russia");

        expandableListDetail.put("CRICKET TEAMS", cricket);
        expandableListDetail.put("FOOTBALL TEAMS", football);
        expandableListDetail.put("BASKETBALL TEAMS", basketball);
        expandableListDetail.put( "TIs",ass );
        return expandableListDetail;
    }
}
```

Getters and Setters if needed.

```
package com.example.myapplicationteeeeeeeeeest;

import java.util.Map;


public class Recipe {

    private String category;
    private long cookingtime;
    private String description;
    private Map<String, Object> amountOfIngredients;
    private String nameOfRecipe;
    private Map<String, Object> Ingredients;

    public Recipe() {};

    public Recipe(String category, long cookingtime, String description,Map<String, Object> amountOfIngredients, String nameOfRecipe, Map<String, Object> Ingridients) {
        this.category=category;
        this.cookingtime=cookingtime;
        this.description=description;
        this.amountOfIngredients=amountOfIngredients;
        this.nameOfRecipe=nameOfRecipe;
        this.Ingredients=Ingridients;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public String getCookingtime() {
        long ct = cookingtime;
        String result = String.valueOf( ct );
        return result;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getAmountOfIngredients() {
        return amountOfIngredients;
    }

    public String getNameOfRecipe() {
        return nameOfRecipe;
    }

    public Map<String, Object> getIngredients() {
        return Ingredients;
    }




}
```

The Fragment

```
public class RecipeTab extends ShoppingRecipe {


    private ListView listView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    private ArrayList<String> recipeList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view1 = inflater.inflate( R.layout.tab_fragment_two, container,false );
        listView = (ListView) view1.findViewById( R.id.recipe_listView1 );


        String[] RecpeitExample = {
                "Example","Example","Example","Example","Example","Example","Example","Example","Example","Example","Example",

        };

        recipeList = new ArrayList<>(  );
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>( getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,RecpeitExample);
        listView.setAdapter( adapter );
        return view1;

    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated never worked with expandable listviews and cant seem to wrap my head around how to get the data into the view. Cheers!